# Expo path problem after updating from` sdk 35` to` sdk 39`

Tags: react-native, expo

I've updated my app from `expo SDK 35` to `expo SDK 39`. After updating it fires an error :

> Failed building JavaScript bundle.
>
> Unable to resolve "../screens/home" from "screens\news\index.js"

My code was working perfectly fine and it looks like this:

`import Home from '../screens/home';`

Can somebody help me with this issue? Because I'm really stuck with that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to close the app and do npm install. Also check if the import is correct.

Comment: Already did that multiple times. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code for the files causing the issue?